# Avoid Elimination by Erasure while mapping over Map

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I want to map over a Map that has the type `List[~(A,Option[B])]` but before I map over it I group it by A. Now that I can map over it, I have to match the Tuple of the Map:

```
val rawData: List[A ~ Option[B]]

rawData
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .map(case (first: A, second: Seq[A ~ Option[B]]) => 
        C(first, second.map(_._2))
    )
```

Now the Compiler warns me:

```
non-variable type argument anorm.~[A,Option[B]] in type pattern Seq[anorm.~[A,Option[B]]] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

I found several solutions to make that matching possible, but I have the feeling, that it could be also possible to avoid the matching at all as I only want to go through that Map that has already a defined Type. How could this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you actually don't have to worry about this. The error is because your case statement is too verbose. Change to the following:

```
rawData.groupBy(_._1).map(case (first, second) => 
  C(first, second.map(_._2))
)
```

The types in the case statement restrict the type of the tuple (which is unnecessary). However, they restrict it in a way which is not verifiable at runtime (due to type erasure), that's why you get the error.

Comment: huh..doesn't seem to work. Now I get the following error: value map is not a member of Any

Comment: @Type On which `map`? In any case this is incredibly strange as the ability to call `map` does note depend on `rawData` at all, given you may call `groupBy`...

Comment: Ah..my error: I had the function in map in a seperate val and hadn't specified the function parameters correctly